# What does uv.zw mean in HLSL?

Tags: graphics, 3d, shader, hlsl

I am trying to use HLSL code as a basis for an experiment, but I don't understand what uv.zw represent? It shows:

```
float4 uv0      : TEXCOORD0
...
uv0.zw;
```

Isn't uv only 2? I know uvw supports 3 but what's the fourth component? Alpha?

In the online examples, I could only found `TEXCOORD0` used for `float2` values, not `float4`.

Answer (score 0):

Textures can be 3D, so texture coordinates can have a third dimension, z.

If you're familiar with homogeneous coordinates, you'll know that one way of representing a variety of transformations on a 3D coordinate is 4D via homogeneous coordinates, which adds a "w" coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

All values in GPU are actually float4's behind the scenes -- declaring things float or float2 etc merely restrict the # of channels that are used.

If a float2 value accesses .zw channels, it's technically undefined but the compiler may accept it. So be cautious.

In HLSL the name "uv" has no intrinsic definition -- you could declare a variable of any type with that name.